# SQL Server CE Cast a date field

Tags: sql-server-ce

I just wrote following query:

```
SELECT CAST(ENTERED AS nvarchar(10)) AS DATE, ITEM_ASSIGNED, COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
FROM DataSheet
GROUP BY CAST(ENTERED AS nvarchar(10)), ITEM_ASSIGNED
```

I am almost there, the only issue I have is that my Entered field is showing as

```
Apr 1 201
```

and I want it to show as:

```
4/1/2013
```

How can I change the format within this query? I am using SQL Server Compact

Comment: Why don't you apply presentation-layer string formatting at the presentation layer, using string formatting functions like `FORMAT()`, instead of asking SQL Server to format a date using a specific string format?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried

```
SELECT   CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ENTERED, 101) AS [DATE]  
       , ITEM_ASSIGNED
       , COUNT(*) AS TOTAL
FROM     DataSheet
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ENTERED, 101), ITEM_ASSIGNED
```